# Inconsistent output of c code when implementing 'split' function

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to implement the 'split()' function from python in C, and with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strsplit(char *, unsigned long *);
void strprint(char *);
void empty_arr(char *);

int main()
{

  char str1[] = "help me out"; // changeable line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  unsigned long str2[strlen(str1)];

  int k = strsplit(&str1, &str2);
  unsigned long *p;
  p = &str2;

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
  {
    printf("%u\n", str2[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}

void strprint(char *s)
{
  while (*s != '\0')
  {
    printf("%c\n", *s);
    s++;
  }
}

void empty_arr(char *a)
{
  while (*a != '\0')
  {
    *a = '\0';
    a++;
  }
}

int strsplit(char *s, unsigned long *n)
{

  int i = 0;
  char temp[50];
  char *t = temp;

  while (1 == 1)
  {
    // printf("*s = %c\n", *s);
    // printf("Length: %u\n\n", strlen(temp));

    if (*s == ' ' || *s == '\0')
    {
      // printf("Entering!\n");
      *n = strlen(temp);
      n++;
      i++;
      empty_arr(temp);
      t = &temp;
      if (*s == '\0')
        break;
    }
    else
    {
      *t = *s;
      t++;
    }

    s++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

The output is:
4
2
3
3

But, when I change str1 (commented with "changeable line") to "help me out man"
then the output I receive is this:
6
2
3
3

With the first input, the function strsplit correctly determines the length of the word 'help' as 4, but with the second input it determines it to be 6.

I have programmed in higher-level languages but never a lower-level one such as C.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `int k = strsplit(&str1, &str2);` should be `int k = strsplit(str1, str2);`. Likewise, `p = &str2;`  should be `p = str2;` and `t = &temp;` should be `t = temp;`. Also, printing `unsigned long` s should not be done with `%u` but `%lu`.

Comment: `temp[]` is uninitialised but you call `strlen()` on it. Suggest adding more warnings to your compilation.

Comment: Even without adding additional warnings, gcc gives loads of warnings for this code. Treat them all as errors, understand them, and fix them. You can't ask us to debug code that does not compile cleanly. If you don't understand a particular warning, that would be a good question to ask.

Comment: Before wasting time hand-rolling functionality, start reading a good beginner's guide to C. You'll find functions like `strtok()` and `memset()` in the C Standard Library that would solve your problem with a few lines of code. Don't try to reinvent the wheel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues noticed:

- `int k = strsplit(&str1, &str2);` should be `int k = strsplit(str1, str2);`.
- `t = &temp;` should be `t = temp;`
- `p = &str2;` should be `p = str2;` - but `p` isn't used, so just remove that.
- Printing `unsigned long` s should not be done with `%u` but `%lu`.
- You should probably initialize `temp` just incase the test-string starts with a space or `\0` because if it does, you'll do `strlen` on an uninitialized string, with *undefined behavior* as a result.

With those changes, and the input `"help me out man"`, your program will print:

```
4
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why attempt to write code when the C Standard Library already provides functionality that you want? If you're familiar with Python, then you should be aware that libraries exist.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[] = "Once upon a time there lived a beautiful princess.", *p = buf;
    char **t = NULL; size_t sz = sizeof *t;
    int n = 0;

    while(!!(t=realloc(t,(n+1)*sz))&&!!(t[n]=strtok(p," .\n"))) p=NULL, n++;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        puts( t[i] );

    free( t );

    return 0;
}
```

A single tight `while()` loop chops the input string on delimiters (like Python's `split()`), storing pointer(s) to each segment into a growing allocated dynamic array.

Result:

```
Once
upon
a
time
there
lived
a
beautiful
princess
```

Learn what's available and proven before wasting time reinventing the wheel.

(Note: A *mutable* string is presumed, and reporting the possible failure of `realloc()` is missing from this example code.)

**EDIT**
There've been a few comments regarding the *density* of the code above. Below is equivalent code (with the benefit of managing a `realloc()` failure.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[] = "Once upon a time there lived a beautiful princess.";
    char *cp = buf;

    char **arr = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    for( ;; )
    {
        cp = strtok( cp, " .\n" );
        if( cp == NULL )
        {
            break;
        }

        char **tmp = realloc( arr, (n+1) * sizeof *tmp );
        if( tmp == NULL )
        {
            perror( "realloc" );
            free( arr ); // release what may have been acquired.
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        arr = tmp;

        arr[ n++ ] = cp;
        cp = NULL;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        puts( arr[i] );

    free( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That while loop scares me. It remind me of my professor who was writing FEMA simulation loops in one line

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It's something... Not APL, but it's something `:-)` (Just made a tiny adjustment... I'd written this for C++, and had left casting the return from `realloc()` in by mistake... Tamed a bit? `:-)`

Comment: The code golf here might be fun (I'll let you know when I stop shivering under my desk) but decompressing this a bit might have more instructional value.

Comment: @Chris Please come out from under there. I disagree that this is an example of "code golf". Decompressing, as an exercise for the OP, will be instructive. The OP is welcome to ask "why?/how?" questions if wishing to understand how this functions. Thanks for the comment! `:-)` Is yours the recent DV?

Comment: Yes. I felt the _density_ of that loop made the answer not useful. As well, using `,` to avoid a set of brackets is a poor habit to be teaching people who likely lack the experience to know when to use it.

Comment: @Chris Fine. You're entitled to your view, of course. Odd that the accepted answer doesn't address the OP's objective: "_trying to implement the 'split()' function from python_". To each their own... imho, it's a bad idea to not recommend that beginners should begin by turning to the documentation instead of wasting time (poorly) re-inventing primitive functionality